# How to post and get results - Java jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I need help. 
I am trying send data to this web page: http://www.coordinadora.com/portafolio-de-servicios/servicios-en-linea/rastrear-guias/ 
this is the data: 62900001810 <- with this number I get information about the 
package sent. but I get: NOT FOUND or Guía no localizada in Spanish. 
All this with JAVA and JSOUP.

this is my code:

```
Connection.Response Form = Jsoup
    .connect("http://www.coordinadora.com/portafolio-de-servicios/servicios-en-linea/rastrear-guias/#rastreo")
    .method(Connection.Method.GET).execute();

    Document document = Jsoup
    .connect("http://www.coordinadora.com/portafolio-de-servicios/servicios-en-linea/rastrear-guias/#rastreo")
    .data("coor_guia_home", guiaNumero.trim()).cookies(Form.cookies()).post();
```

and I get this (part of the result) when I parsing:

```
<div class="coor_alert_msg">
      Guia no localizada
     </div>
```

I should get something like this:

[Result I should get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKdlF.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending incorrect form data. If you will examine what data are send with the post for example with debugger tools in your browser you will find out that this form has two fields:

```
coor_guia   
coor_guia_home
```

Your second request should look like this:

```
  Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://www.coordinadora.comportafolio-de-servicios/servicios-en-linea/rastrear-guias/#rastreo")
    .data("coor_guia", guiaNumero.trim())
    .data("coor_guia_home", "true")
    .cookies(Form.cookies())
    .post();
```

Comment: Thanks very much!.

Comment: Thank you very much!. With the emotion I wrote bad xD